# Why JMeter Ultimate Thread Groups create incorrect number of users?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When I'm using the original JMeter Thread Groups and set 10 threads (users), it fires 10 external HTTP calls.

When I changed it to Ultimate Thread Groups (UTG) and set the following attributes...

- Start Threads Count = 10
- Initial Delay = 0
- Startup Time = 60
- Hold Load For = 30
- Shutdown Time = 10

...it fires thousands of external HTTP calls. Even the Stepping Thread Groups (STG) and Concurrency Thread Groups (CTG) also behave the same as UTG.

Why this happens when using non-original JMeter thread groups? I'm looking for ways to create 10 users that create 1 external HTTP call each (means 10 in total for the whole test plan) using UTG, STG or CTG but I don't really understand why this happens.

**Screenshots when using original Thread Group**

[image]

[image]

**Screenshots when using original Ultimate Thread Group**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It creates **correct** number of users, you see higher number of [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) because you're running your test for 100 seconds with more or less 10 virtual users and each user executes Samplers as fast as it can.

If you want to limit JMeter's throughput in order to send 10 requests in 100 seconds - you need to send 1 request in 10 seconds, it can be done using [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/).